# Xcode 6: Why this code doesn't compile now?

Tags: ios, xcode, properties

My code was compiling and running great until I upgraded to Xcode 6.

Definition shows a Warning : Auto property synthesis will not synthesize property 'hash' because it is 'readwrite' but it will be synthesized 'readonly' via another property

```
@property (nonatomic, strong)               NSString       *hash;       // (get/compute) hash code of the place (master hash of images)
```

Implementation shows error whenever I access to _hash: Use of undeclared identifier '_hash'

```
-(NSString *)hash {
    if (_hash) return _hash;

    // If place id, take it as the hash code
    NSString *poiID = self.info[@"id"];
    if (poiID) {
        _hash = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"id-%lu",(unsigned long)[self.address hash]];
    }
    else if (CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(self.location.coordinate)) {
        NSString *seed = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", self.location.coordinate.latitude, self.location.coordinate.longitude];
        _hash = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"location-%lu",(unsigned long)[seed hash]];
    }
    else if (self.address) {
        NSString *seed = self.address;
        _hash = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"address-%lu",(unsigned long)[seed hash]];
    }
    else {
        _hash = @"POI-unknownIDLocationOrAddress";
    }

    return _hash;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following line to auto generate the setter method:

```
@synthesize hash = _hash;
```

If you don't want a setter method and only want a read-only property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSString *hash;
```

Comment: Ok. We now must explicitly declare auto synthesis with @synthesize hash = _hash;

Comment: Take a look at the section [When To Supply The Instance Variable](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/08/01/property-synthesis-with-xcode-4-dot-4.html) in this article from 2012 about Xcode 4.4

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't compile because hash is already part of NSObject:

See:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/hash

Comment: In other words, name your property anything but "hash".